# How to use parser GSON for Json,in Android Studio

Tags: android, json, android-studio, gson

My Json data .

```
{
"data":[
{
"id":"49",
"title":"Dsd",
"date":"2016-09-09 12:15:35",
"descr":"Slader",
"full_story":"Testsdsdfsdffsd",
"images":"2016-09/1472831591.jpg",
"news_read":"4049",
"rating":"150",
"genre":[
     "111",
     "222",
     "333"
]
},
```

I'm using plugin for Android studio is "DTO from JSON", and here is code

```
    public class GetDataGSON {

    @SerializedName("data")
    public List<Data> data;

    public static class Data {
        @SerializedName("id")
        public String id;
        @SerializedName("title")
        public String title;
        @SerializedName("date")
        public String date;
        @SerializedName("descr")
        public String descr;
        @SerializedName("full_story")
        public String full_story;
        @SerializedName("images")
        public String images;
        @SerializedName("news_read")
        public String news_read;
        @SerializedName("rating")
        public String rating;
        @SerializedName("genre")
        public List<Genre> genre;
    }
}
```

In this line for some reason I get the error

```
@SerializedName("genre")
            public List<Genre> genre;
```

Cannot resolve symbol 'Genre'

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You need to create a `Genre` class and model the Genre data

Comment: I do not know kak.Vse done automatically . Across plugin Android studio "DTO from JSON":)

Comment: This is NOT DUPLICATE!!! 
1) I am using annotations.  
2) people on your link makes everything by hand.

different posts

Answer (score 1):

According to you `JSON`, the data inside `genre` list are just `String`'s. So write:

```
@SerializedName("genre")
public List<String> genre;
```

However, if the data is more complicated, create model `Genre`:

```
public class Genre {
    //parameters
}
```

Comment: Accept the answer, if it works for you. Maybe Other users would have the same problem.

Comment: wait 4 minutes. SO. does not push the button